# VB.Net vs C# Expression Tree Differences

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ query that is textually very similar in both C# and VB.net. I am attempting to load all orders from a Northwind database using [BLToolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/). This is my Order class. Notice that the OrderDate DateTime is a Nullable DateTime.

```
[TableName("Orders")]
public class Order : EntityBase<int>
{
    public int OrderID;
    public DateTime? OrderDate;
}
```

The C# linq code is:

```
from ord in Order
where ord.OrderDate == new DateTime(1997, 11, 14)
select ord.OrderID
```

The VB linq code is:

```
From order In db.Order _
Where order.OrderDate = #11/14/1997#
Select order.OrderID
```

When executed, the C# code generates this expression tree:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
        .Constant<BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Table`1[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order]>(Table(Order)),
        '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Boolean]>)),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Int32]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Boolean]>(Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order $order) {
    $order.OrderDate == (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]).New System.DateTime(
        1997,
        11,
        14)
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Int32]>(Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order $order) {
    $order.OrderID
}
```

and the VB code generates this expression tree:

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Where(
        .Constant<BLToolkit.Data.Linq.Table`1[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order]>(Table(Order)),
        '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Boolean]>)),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Int32]>))

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Boolean]>(Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order $order) {
    $order.OrderDate == (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]).New System.DateTime(
        1997,
        11,
        14) ?? False
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order,System.Int32]>(Data.Linq.Model.Northwind+Order $order) {
    $order.OrderID
}
```

Why is VB sticking on `?? False` to the end of the OrderDate comparison, and what meaning does that have?

[Related issue report on BLToolkit](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues/318)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Are you having issues with one working and not the other?

Comment: Yes, BLToolkit is an ORM, which translates the LINQ query into a SQL query.  It is not handling the `?? False` that VB is inserting.

Comment: Have you tried with `New DateTime(...)` in the VB version?

Comment: Yes, it generates a very similar expression tree, still containing the `?? False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET handles nullable types a bit different than C# so VB.NET can be backwards compatible with VB6.

A C# nullable that is Null is an actual Null, and translates so in LINQ to SQL.

A VB nullable that is Nothing has a default value defined internally, as VB6 doesn't have a true "NULL" value. The nullable field's property ".Value" returns Nothing if the internal value is this default, while LINQ uses the internal value directly.

The "?? False" is LINQ's way of handling this "Not really a Null" property, so LINQ to Objects doesn't throw a fit when using Nullable types.  This doesn't get translated to SQL.

In VB LINQ to SQL Queries using Nullable types, you have to pair the regular Where clause with an "IsNot Nothing" or "field.HasValue" check.  This avoids having LINQ implicitly create the "is this null" check.

Example:

```
Dim result = From row In Table _
             Where row.nullableField.HasValue AndAlso row.nullableField = someValue _
             Select row
```

Or

```
Dim result = From row In Table _
             Where row.nullableField IsNot Nothing AndAlso row.nullableField = anotherValue _
             Select row
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed to know. In LINQ to SQL it does not get translated into the final SQL, however I am dealing with a non MS, open source ORM, BLToolkit. Looks like the bug is they don't handle VB's weird Nullable handling. Points for you!